# Policy based routing in linux based on destination address.

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, ip-routing, openswan

I am struggling with a scenario. Suppose we have two systems in same subnet A:- 192.168.1.5 and B:-192.168.1.6 where B is further connected with C:-172.22.1.5 through Openswan. B can ping C but A cant ping C.

I want to add a route in A that it route all traffic which is destined for 172.22.1.5 to B.

I used `route add -net 172.22.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.6 dev eth0` But it is not working. Checked with tcpdump and packets are not going to B.

Any ideas how this can be done ?

Comment: Please show the complete routing table on host A. Also, show the IP addresses of both ends of Openswan tunnel and their routing tables.

Comment: 172.22.1.0/24 is in AWS and Openswan is connected to AWS VPC VPN. AWS side Security groups are open and there is no iptables on aws side.     Route table of A is as below                                
                                                                                                
10.0.0.0/21 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.105
172.22.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.6 dev eth1
64.22.106.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 64.22.106.56

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish your goal, both ends must have respective routes to the other end.

So, in your case:

`route add -net 172.22.1.0/24 gw 192.168.1.6 dev eth0` in Host A.

`route add 192.168.1.5 gw 172.22.1.N dev X` in Host C. Here `N` is the address of Host B in the VPN subnet, and `X` is the device used for the VPN subnet in Host C.